# Shared Mailboxes - What are my options?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, shared-mailbox

I need help...

**Background:**

I was employed to manage the online content for a small, seasonal rental company, (the kind where they work the summer to survive the winter) and that quickly turned into also managing their IT when they discovered I was "good with computers".  We had a major issue with emails yesterday where 2 days worth of emails just disappeared from the outlook .pst file never to return (I had local backups so actual damage was minimal).  So, my boss asked me to see what I could do to improve the current setup for as little cost as possible (he's not trying to get something for nothing, just has minimal budget because of the business type)

Please keep in mind through all of this that e-mail is not my strong point.

**The current setup**

- We have 3 mail accounts info@, bookings@, admin@
- We have 3 computers, all which need access to the 3 mailboxes at the same time
- Currently all accounts come via POP into a single pst file on one computer, which then uses simpleSYN to replicate the file for each of the other computers.  They can then manage emails and replicate back and forth so that all 3 systems see the same email view.

The current setup is cumbersome, and seems fraught with danger by live replicating pst files.  Corruptions reportedly happen every so often, and days of emails disappearing has apparently happened before.  The other issue is that PC A also has to be on all the time otherwise pc B and C don't get emails.

**The solution**

It seems to me that some kind of shared mailbox would the best option, having used them in the past for other jobs, but I have no idea how they work or how to set one up.  All google is telling me is that it can be done via Microsoft Exchange, but I can't seem to find any other option to compare it to, and I genuinely cannot access the admin panel on our 365 account to see if we have that option on our subscription.

IMAP isn't really an option as a) our hosting plan comes with 500mb email per account, and b) the boss is super paranoid about emails so wants them kept locally.

---

So, what are my options?

I am looking for some kind of shared mailbox that is:

- Economical
- Does not require any kind of networking qualification to set up
- Low risk of losing emails (I currently keep daily local backups of the pst files)
- Can keep our current email addresses

**note:** I am also going to be setting up a server to host the booking system (the bosses PC also has to be on all the time for that to work) and for all documents (currently in dropbox and running out of space). I'm not sure if that could be part of the solution or not.

Apologies for the long post, but wanted to give as much info as possible.

Cheers in advance...

Comment: You might start by not using POP but instead IMAP which would leave the mails on the server and which supports access from multiple sources. If he's that paranoid an stores important documents on Dropbox he really shouldn't be that concerned. In addition if the current plan isn't sufficient ask the hoster for an upgrade. With your current requirements you're probably at a point where you won't get much better. Short of getting better hosting or running your own mail server.

Comment: Here's some good advice: Never let the person who set this up touch your computers ever again.

Comment: Do your users need to *send* email from the three email addresses, or simply receive email from them and send with a single, shared address?

Comment: Yes,  send and receive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Microsoft Outlook, and Microsoft Exchange (Office 365 can be configured as an exchange account) you can simply enable "Restore Deleted Items" which allows you to bring back these emails.

The only thing you need to know, is where they were deleted from, but this usually is not a problem.

Depending on what version of outlook you are using, it may not be enabled by default though, but with a simple registry change, you can enable this per client.

Here is what you need to do:

1. Open the registry.
2. Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINESOFTWARE\Microsoft\Exchange\Client\Options.
3. Add a DWORD value named DumpsterAlwaysOn and set it to 1.
4. Restart Microsoft Outlook to make the change take effect.

The button `Recover Deleted Items` can be found in the `Folder` tab, or be assigned to the quick commands bar if not available in the `Folder` tab.

See also: https://www.msoutlook.info/question/685

If you really want to keep things locally, consider a local exchange server and popcon to download all mail locally. Then the above will work.

Comment: *consider a local exchange server*...This of course would be ideal, but the OP did say budget was a concern, so this is clearly out of the question.

Comment: @Twisty Agreed, but can you think of an alternative? If so, by all means write an answer yourself.

Comment: I have been given the OK for a small server, (possibly, depending on Summer revenue ) so if I can make that work, it might be the solution.

Comment: Awesome. You can actually use other software as mail servers too, but exchange with outlook is definitely a preferred combination.

Comment: Thanks @LPChip, I have marked yours as the best answer as you gave me an avenue to research.  Using exchange locally with something link popcon didn't come up in my original searches, so I am investigating that further now.  Will sort the pros/cons and speak to my boss